# Product rule for Hessian matrix

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, products

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Is there a general formula for the Hessian matrix of their product?

That is, what is $H(f(x) g(x))$, where $H(f(x)) = \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right)_{i,j = 1 \dots n}$?

Comment: suggest you write out in agonizing detail for $n=1$ and then $n=2.$

Answer (score 6):

It follows from [theorem 40.1(b) on p. 360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaAiX.jpg) (the product rule) and from [corollary 39.7 on p. 351](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDi5s.jpg) (the differential in terms of the partial differentials) of Robert G. Bartle's "The Elements of Real Analysis", 2nd edition (John Wiley & Sons, 1976), that if $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, if $f, g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and if $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is such that both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $c$, then $fg$ is likewise differentiable at $c$, all the partial derivatives of $f$, $g$, and $fg$ are well defined at $c$, and the following holds:
$$
\nabla_c(fg) = (\nabla_cf)g(c) + f(c)\nabla_cg \tag{*}
$$
where $\nabla_cf$ is $f$'s gradient at $c$ (and analogously $\nabla_cg$ and $\nabla_c(fg)$). In other words $\nabla_cf$ (and analogously $\nabla_cg$, $\nabla_c(fg)$) is the $n$-dimensional row vector, whose components are $f$'s partial derivatives at $c$:
$$
\nabla_cf = [D_1f(c), \dots, D_nf(c)]
$$
(This gradient is defined in [exercise 39.J(a) on p. 357](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92NLC.jpg) of Bartle's text.)

Therefore, if $f, g$ are differentiable in a neighborhood of $c$ and if $D_1f, D_1g, \dots, D_nf, D_ng$ are all differentiable at $c$, the Hessian matrix of $fg$ is well defined at $c$ (and likewise the Hessian matrices at $c$ of $f$ and of $g$) and its transpose is given by
$$\begin{split}
H_c(fg)^T
& =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\nabla_cD_1(fg) \\
\vdots \\
\nabla_cD_n(fg)
\end{array}\right] \\
& =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\nabla_c\left((D_1f)g + fD_1g\right) \\
\vdots \\
\nabla_c\left((D_nf)g + fD_ng\right)
\end{array}\right] \\
& =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\nabla_c\left((D_1f)g\right) \\
\vdots \\
\nabla_c\left((D_nf)g\right)
\end{array}\right]
+
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\nabla_c\left(fD_1g\right) \\
\vdots \\
\nabla_c\left(fD_ng\right)
\end{array}\right] \\
& =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\left(\nabla_cD_1f\right)g(c) \\
\vdots \\
\left(\nabla_cD_nf\right)g(c)
\end{array}\right]
+
\left[\begin{array}{c}
D_1f(c)\nabla_cg \\
\vdots \\
D_nf(c)\nabla_cg
\end{array}\right]
+
\left[\begin{array}{c}
(\nabla_cf)D_1g(c) \\
\vdots \\
(\nabla_cf)D_ng(c)
\end{array}\right]
+
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f(c)\nabla_cD_1g \\
\vdots \\
f(c)\nabla_cD_ng
\end{array}\right] \\
& =
H_cf^Tg(c) + \nabla_cf^T\nabla_cg + \nabla_cg^T\nabla_cf + f(c)H_cg^T
\end{split}
$$
That is, $H_c(fg)$'s transpose is the vertical concatenation of the $n$ gradients at $c$ of the $n$ partial derivatives $D_1(fg), \dots, D_n(fg)$, respectively. The second and fourth equations are a result of $(*)$ and the third is due to the linearity of differentiation.

Transposing and rearranging the terms, we obtain
$$
H_c(fg) = (H_cf)g(c) + \nabla_cf^T\nabla_cg + \nabla_cg^T\nabla_cf + f(c)H_cg
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the product is a function:

$$P:\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R$$
$$(x,y)\longmapsto xy$$
and your function is a composition
$$\Bbb R^n\overset{\Delta}\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\overset{(f,g)}\longrightarrow\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\overset{P}\longrightarrow\Bbb R$$
$$x\longmapsto\pmatrix{x\cr x}\longmapsto\pmatrix{f(x)\cr g(x)}\longmapsto f(x)g(x)$$
Apply the chain rule two times.