# Jacobian of the Product of Two Functions

Tags: real-analysis, jacobian

> **Question:** Let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: V \to \mathbb{R}$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ both open.
>   Now suppose we take the product of these two functions, i.e. formally
>   the product rule
>
> $$\mathbf{D}(fg)(a) = g\mathbf{D}f(a) + f\mathbf{D}g(a)$$

How would we construct a formula for the Jacobian of $f \cdot g$?

What I have so far is that

$$
\begin{align*}
g\mathbf{D}f(a) + f\mathbf{D}g(a) &= g\mathbf{D}
\begin{pmatrix}
f_1(\mathbf{a}) \\
\vdots \\
f_n(\mathbf{a})
\end{pmatrix}
+ 
f\mathbf{D}
\begin{pmatrix}
g_1(\mathbf{a}) \\
\vdots \\
g_n(\mathbf{a})
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= g
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial a_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial a_n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_n}{a_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial a_n}
\end{pmatrix}
+ f
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial a_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial a_n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial g_n}{a_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial g_n}{\partial a_n}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}$$
Do we simply multiply through $g$ and $f$ and add the two?

Comment: Possible related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997193/product-rule-for-hessian-matrix